# ElasticSearch NEST TLS version

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, ssl, tls1.2, nest

When working with NEST C# sdk - how can I specific the TLS version?

I went over the interfaces of ElasticClient/ConnectionSettings but couldn't find any property that looks right for that.

The purpose is to ensure that the minimum TLS version is higher than 1.0

Thanks!

Comment: Adding static method at beginning of the code will work : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  The client specifies the version at putting in you code should work.

Comment: thanks @jdweng
i think it will also have impact on all other client connections that will be create by my application, is that right?
is there a way to specify it to the ElasticSearch connection only?

Comment: Old versions of TLS are obsolete and should not be used.  Only TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are valid.  Microsoft did a security push last June and disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on servers.